# Fail to extract gender information from a single name in R

Tags: r, json, api

I have a problem extracting the gender information from the first name. I have a bunch of email addresses and I used one regular expression pattern to extract the first name information. It contains some non-first names information and then I need to tell whether it's a first name before extracting the gender information. It returns me an error and I cannot fix it by myself. Any suggestions or help? Really appreciate it.

Here is my dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kQAcjo2Ewuy43SLK111NwFerNiv_tbPK/view?usp=share_link

Here is my code:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(lexicon)

# API endpoint URL
url <- "https://api.genderize.io"

df <- read.csv("TESTNAME.csv")
email_test <- df$x

# Get list of common first names from reference corpus
first_names <- freq_first_names[["Name"]]

# Filter out non-first name information
names <- tolower(email_test)[tolower(email_test) %in% tolower(first_names)]

# Function to call Genderize.io API and extract gender information for a single name
get_gender <- function(name) {
  response <- GET(paste0(url, "?name=", name))
  data <- content(response, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
  json <- fromJSON(data)
  if (json$gender != "") {
    return(json$gender)
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}

# Apply get_gender function to each name in the list
genders <- sapply(names, get_gender)

# Combine names and genders into a data frame
df <- data.frame(name = names, gender = genders)

# Print the result
df
```

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: Most likely the results of your API call don’t have an element called `"gender"`, or that element is empty. I would look at your `json` object to make sure the API returned anything, and if so what the element names are.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If it cannot connect the first name information to the gender in this way, do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!